# Using Logback but Log4j started displaying WARN no Appenders

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am using logback for my logging and it has been working however; the other day I started getting a warning

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

I am not using log4j nor have I ever with this project. 
I have a logback.xml in my resources folder.

Any ideas on why this warning started to show up?

Comment: Axis uses log4J : org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle. Did you change your logback file to a different logging level? (trace vs debug)

Comment: What is Axis? and yes I did change it to DEBUG from TRACE

Comment: I believe I found out where Axis is being used. I am using a library: org.swift.common:jira-soap:4.4.0 which uses axis:1.4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must be using a library that does use log4j. Can you post anything more about your project?

You should probably just put log4j bridge on the classpath. Read more here:
http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

The jar you want to look into is log4j-over-slf4j. It will bridge log4j API to actually make calls to your implementation of slf4j API (in your case - logback).

If you are using Maven to build your project then it might be as simple as putting

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

in dependencies.

Excluding a library (if needed) would be done in this fashion (this assumes we are talking about the transitive dependency from the jar you've mentioned):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swift.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-soap</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>...</groupId>
                <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: See comment above about jira library that uses axis

Comment: ... and excluding any log4j jars that are pulled in as transitive dependencies of anything else.

Comment: @Ian - that's correct. Chris - in case if you're unfamiliar with Maven then check out dependencies management section of the docs: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html (that is only relevant if you are indeed using Maven for this :))

Comment: @IanRoberts excluding the log4j dependency that maven auto imported fixed the issue. However, I did not have to add the <exclude> tag in the pom.xml file instead I just used Intillj's project settings for the libraries included and just removed it from that list.

Comment: I am still assuming that you are using Maven :)
I do see that the artifact you've mentioned uses commons-logging - if you'd need to exclude this dependency you'd do it like I've mentioned in the last part of the edited answer.

      <dependency>
   <groupId>org.swift.common</groupId>
   <artifactId>jira-soap</artifactId>
   <version>4.4.0</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: @theadam I had the same problem. Very confusing since it told me that Log4j was the problem not commons-logging

Comment: @theadam although you are mentioning about log4j-over-slf4j, your maven first dependency is slf4j-log4j12 which is not a bridge but rather chanelling slf4j to log4j? Sorry i dont understand

Comment: @dimitrisli you are right, that was a mistake on my part, I wonder how I never caught it. slf4j-log4j12 is log4j binding for slf4j, I've updated the maven dependency above. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Took me some time to find out since the message was log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger

I tried to exclude log4j and I tried the log4j-over-slf4j.

Then I ran mvn dependency:tree and finally found out that mye commons-configuration actually was using commons-logging

```
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
```

This became the solution for me.

```
    <!-- logging with logback (and slf4j)-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- had a dep in commons-configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: According to http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html common-loggings should be removed from the dependency list in pom.xml.